# AppEngine Standard Node.js app deployment fails with Out of Memory error deleting node modules?

Tags: memory, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

We have an App Engine standard application using nodejs10 runtime which has begun failing deployment with the following error output:

```
... trimmed
Step #1 - "builder": INFO npm_install took 46 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmpXKvzdH.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/srv/node_modules/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO `tar_runtime_package` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO tar_runtime_package took 26 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: gzip_tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpXKvzdH.tar -1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO `gzip_tar_runtime_package` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO gzip_tar_runtime_package took 28 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO starting: rm_node_modules
Step #1 - "builder": INFO rm_node_modules rm -rf /workspace/node_modules
Step #1 - "builder": INFO rm_node_modules took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO building_packages_json_layer took 109 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO build process for FTL image took 233 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO full build took 255 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR rm_node_modules rm -rf /workspace/node_modules
Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Step #1 - "builder": rm_node_modules is likely not on the path
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder": "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder": exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 60, in main
Step #1 - "builder": File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 77, in InternalErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
```

There's no package failures… we didn't recently include any new packages in our package.json… The previous release ran just fine with only some changes in our javascript code. The build appears to have completed successfully, but then fails on a clean up step.

I couldn't find any reference to similar errors in superuser.com, has anybody ever run into this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I just got a very similar error, but using Python.

Comment: Yes, EvanM's comment below was actually the exact reason. We had accidentally included puppeteer as a dependency and not a *dev* dependency. Moving puppeteer to devDependencies solved it for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer had been bumped at exactly the time these failures started. Forcing puppeteer to 1.17.0 in `package.json` fixed the issue.